# How members of grandparent class are treated in case of virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I read the following piece of code somewhere, as an example to solve the diamond problem in case of multiple inheritance :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
int x;

public:
    A() {}
    A(int i) { x = i; }
    void print() { cout << x; }
};

class B: virtual public A
{
public:
    B():A(10) { }
};

class C: virtual public A 
{
public:
    C():A(100) { }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose class `D` is defined as follows :

```
class D: public B, public C 
    {
    public:
        D():B(),C(){}
    };
```

I get some garbage value in the print. And if the class `D` is defined as follows (parameterized constructor for A is explicitly called) :

```
class D: public B, public C 
    {
    public:
        D():B(),C(),A(20){}
    };
```

I get 20 as output. In the first case, I can understand that the default `A()` constructor is called, hence the garbage value as x is not set to any value.

However, in the second case, its not clear. When is the parameterized constructor for `A(int)` is called? If I understood correctly, call order depends on order of inheritance. Since `B` is inherited first, `B`'s constructor call takes precedence over `C`.Since `B` inherits `A`, `A()` will be called first, of all. Then `B`'s constructor will be called. Then `C`'s constructor will be called. At last, `A(int)` will be called, as `A`'s constructor is called explicitly in class `D`. If this is the case, then the output is well justified for the second case. However, this, then contradicts the output for the below piece of code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Person {
public:
    Person(int x) { cout << "Person::Person(int ) called" << endl; }
    Person()     { cout << "Person::Person() called" << endl; }
};

class Faculty : virtual public Person {
public:
    Faculty(int x):Person(x) {
    cout<<"Faculty::Faculty(int ) called"<< endl;
    }
};

class Student : virtual public Person {
public:
    Student(int x):Person(x) {
        cout<<"Student::Student(int ) called"<< endl;
    }
};

class TA : public Faculty, public Student {
public:
    TA(int x):Student(x), Faculty(x), Person(x) {
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    TA ta1(30);
}
```

The output for this program :

```
Person::Person(int ) called
Faculty::Faculty(int ) called
Student::Student(int ) called
TA::TA(int ) called
```

Why `Person(int)` called at the beginning in this case, and not at the last?

Answer (score 2):

N4594 12.6.2/13:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - **First**, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), **virtual base classes are initialized in
>     the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes**,
>     where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list .
> - Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>     (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>     (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> - Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
>
> [ Note: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in the
>   reverse order of initialization. —end note ]

Answer (score 1):

Construction always starts from the base `class`. If there are multiple base `class`es then, it starts from the left most base. (**side note**: If there is a `virtual` inheritance then it's given higher preference). Then it comes the turn for member fields. They are initialized in the order they are declared. At the last the `class` itself is constructed.

The order of destructor is exactly reverse

Answer (score 0):

With virtual inheritance, constructor of the virtual class is called only in the most derived class.

And order of initialization doesn't depend of order of initialization list, but to the order of declaration inside the class.

Comment: This answer explains *where* shall constructor of virtual base class be called. OP asked *when* is that constructor of virtual base class called.

Comment: @PcAF: I may be unclear, but it was the goal of my second paragraph.

Comment: Well, I think that *order of declaration (of base classes) inside class* is unclear term.

Answer (score 0):

> Since B inherits A, A() will be called first, of all. Then B's
>   constructor will be called.

This is not quite true when `A` is virtually inherited.

When a class is virtually inherited, it is effectively inherited by the most derived class, for the purpose of invoking constructors and destructors. That's what virtual inheritance between.

Since `D` derives from `B` and `C`, in that class hierarchy `D` inherits `A` when it comes to invoking constructors and destructors, because `D` is the most-derived class.